# Fixed Error ORA-00918

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create TFIDF table. Below is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE TF_IDF2 (FILEID, WORD, TFIDF)AS
select TF.FILEID, TF.WORD, (TF.FREQ*B.IDF) AS TFIDF
from TF JOIN IDF B
ON TF.WORD=B.WORD;
```

Error message:

> SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"`.

The error points to `WORD` in the last line of the query. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the lost line of the code.

Comment: Why are you using `group by` when you don't have an aggregate function? (If you did need one they'd need to specify which table you're using there too, i.e. `group bt TF.WORD`; but you don't seem to here).

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
CREATE TABLE TF_IDF2 AS
select TF.FILEID, TF.WORD, (TF.FREQ * B.IDF) AS TFIDF
from TF JOIN IDF B
ON TF.WORD=B.WORD;
```